# FileUpload java salva arquivos em uma pasta inadequada

Tags: java, jsf, file-upload

Achei um exemplo de fileupload na internet e adicionei no meu projeto., Porém, ele sobe os arquivos para uma pasta dentro do servidor do glashfish. Essa pasta tem o nome de `/config`, e todo o caminho que eu coloco para ele criar, ele cria somente dentro dessa pasta `config`. Mas a aplicação fica em uma outra pasta chamada `Aplications`.

Como faço para que quando ele subir o arquivo, ele faça o upload para as pastas do `webcontent` do projeto? O caminho é setado na variável `path_to`.

```
package model;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.context.ExternalContext;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.http.Part;

public class FileUpload {

    private final int limit_max_size = 10240000;
    private final String limit_type_file = "gif|jpg|png|jpeg|pdf|doc|docx|txt";
    private String path_to = "";

    public FileUpload() {

    }

    public String processUpload(Part fileUpload) {
        String fileSaveData = "noimages.jpg";

        try {

            if (fileUpload.getSize() > 0) {
                String submittedFileName = getFilename(fileUpload);
                if (checkFileType(submittedFileName)) {
                    if (fileUpload.getSize() > this.limit_max_size) {
                        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null,
                                new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "File size too large!", ""));
                    } else {
                        String currentFileName = submittedFileName;
                        String extension = currentFileName.substring(currentFileName.lastIndexOf("."),
                                currentFileName.length());
                        long nameRadom = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
                        String newfilename = currentFileName;

                        fileSaveData = newfilename;
                        String fileSavePath = path_to;

                        try {
                            byte[] fileContent = new byte[(int) fileUpload.getSize()];
                            InputStream in = fileUpload.getInputStream();
                            in.read(fileContent);

                            File fileToCreate = new File(fileSavePath, newfilename);

                            File folder = new File(fileSavePath);
                            if (!folder.exists()) {
                                folder.mkdirs();
                            }
                            FileOutputStream fileOutStream = new FileOutputStream(fileToCreate);
                            fileOutStream.write(fileContent);
                            fileOutStream.flush();
                            fileOutStream.close();
                            fileSaveData = newfilename;
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            fileSaveData = "noimages.jpg";
                        }

                    }

                } else {
                    fileSaveData = "noimages.jpg";

                }

            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            fileSaveData = "noimages.jpg";

        }
        return fileSaveData;
    }

    public String getPath_to() {
        return path_to;
    }

    public void setPath_to(String path_to) {
        this.path_to = path_to;
    }

    private String getFilename(Part part) {

        for (String cd : part.getHeader("content-disposition").split(";")) {
            if (cd.trim().startsWith("filename")) {
                String filename = cd.substring(cd.indexOf('=') + 1).trim().replace("\"", "");

                return filename.substring(filename.lastIndexOf('/') + 1).substring(filename.lastIndexOf('\\') + 1);

            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    private boolean checkFileType(String fileName) {
        if (fileName.length() > 0) {
            String[] parts = fileName.split("\\.");
            if (parts.length > 0) {
                String extention = parts[parts.length - 1];
                return this.limit_type_file.contains(extention);
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Subir arquivos dentro da pasta `webcontent` seria a meu ver uma falha de segurança, pois supondo que o upload fosse uma coisa que você oferecesse a seus usuários, isso permitiria que qualquer um deles acabasse por alterar o conteúdo da aplicação. É verdade que você talvez não esteja oferecendo isso a usuários comuns, e somente a administradores, mas a possibilidade de oferecer a usuários comuns já evidencia o risco.

Comment: Certo, mas se ele esta subindo para a pasta config, como posso acessar ela, para exibir as imagens no html ?  porque eu guardo o caminho que foi salvo no banco e depois coloco o caminho  dentro do src da tag img

Comment: Ou o correto seria eu guardar em uma pasta no computador e não dentro da aplicação?

Comment: Sim, provavelmente guardar em uma pasta pré-definida é bem melhor que tentar colocar dentro da aplicação. A funcionalidade de download para alguém visualizar a imagem depois ou exibi-la em alguma página, pode ser implementada por meio de um servlet ou coisa semelhante.